# Why is a Fourier operator of the exponenetial of a multiplication operator equal to the exponential of a Fourier operator of the multipl. operator?

Tags: operator-theory, fourier-transform

I am going through Dr Frederic Schuller's course on Quantum Theory. The operators that follow are defined on Schwartz space $S(\mathbb{R}^d)$. $H_{free}$ is a self-adjoint operator $H=-\Delta$, $\mathfrak{F}$ and $\mathfrak{F}^{-1}$ are Fourier and inverse Fourier operators on the same space. $P^2$ is a multiplication operator such that:
$$\mathfrak{F}(H_{free})(p)=|p|^{2}(\mathfrak{F}\psi)(p)=:P^{2}\mathfrak{F}(\psi)(p)=(P^{2}\hat{\psi})(p).$$
Also, $|p|^2=p_{1}^{2}+p_{2}^{2}+p_{3}^{2}$.

I know how to get to:
$$H_{free}=\mathfrak{F}^{-1}P^{2}\mathfrak{F}$$

so

$$e^{-itH_{free}}=e^{-it\mathfrak{F}^{-1}P^{2}\mathfrak{F}}$$

I tried various things to get to the following but failed:

$$e^{-it\mathfrak{F}^{-1}P^{2}\mathfrak{F}}=\mathfrak{F}^{-1}e^{-itP^{2}}\mathfrak{F}.$$

I tried writing the exponential as a Lebesgue integral of the projection-valued measure from the Spectral Theorem and I tried using the definitions of the Fourier operator and the inverse Fourier operator, but I can's see a way forward.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = -itP^{2}$, then what you are asking is $e^{\mathfrak{F}^{-1}A\mathfrak{F}}=\mathfrak{F}^{-1}e^{A}\mathfrak{F}$. Or I may have misunderstood the question (?).
If my assumption is correct:

Note that it is easy to show that  $(\mathfrak{F}^{-1}A\mathfrak{F})^n=\mathfrak{F}^{-1}A^{n}\mathfrak{F}$ (expand the term and note that $\mathfrak{F} \mathfrak{F}^{-1}=1$ (1 being the the identity operator)). And by expanding the exponential:

$e^{\mathfrak{F}^{-1}A\mathfrak{F}}=1+\mathfrak{F}^{-1}A\mathfrak{F}+\frac{1}{2!}(\mathfrak{F}^{-1}A\mathfrak{F})^2+...=1+\mathfrak{F}^{-1}A\mathfrak{F}+\mathfrak{F}^{-1}\frac{1}{2!}A^2\mathfrak{F}+...=\mathfrak{F}^{-1}(1+A+\frac{1}{2!}A^2+...)\mathfrak{F}$,

which is $\mathfrak{F}^{-1}e^{A}\mathfrak{F}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work because the operators are on the Hilbert space of (Lebesgue) square integrable functions, which is (uncountably) infinite dimensional. So, the operators can't be represented by matrices and the Taylor expansion can't be used. Instead, since H is self-adjoint, the exponential can be represented by a Lebesgue integral and the associated projection valued measure from the Spectral Theorem. I think I managed to solve it by swapping the order of integration as possible by the Fubini's theorem, which I think applies here.